# How to save an entry in Tkinter to later use in a calculation, then print the answer inside the Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a program which calculates 3-4 values using some user inputted values

I have tried making a function which saves the entries into variables, and making the variables global but that didn't work

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *
root = Tk()

label1 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for length ")
label1.grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "W")
length = Entry(root)
length.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

label2 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for volume ")
label2.grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "W")
volume = Entry(root)
volume.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

label3 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for the thickness of the cylinder ")
label3.grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "W")
thickness = Entry(root)
thickness.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

label4 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for starting temperature ")
label4.grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "W")
st_T = Entry(root)
st_T.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

label5 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for finishing temperature ")
label5.grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "W")
end_T = Entry(root)
end_T.grid(row = 4, column = 2)

def save():
    v = volume.get()
    l = length.get()
    w = thickness.get()
    t0 = st_T.get()
    t1 = end_T.get()

    global values 
    values = [v, l, w, t1, t0]

Button(root, text = "Submit", command = save).grid(row = 6, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

I know the current code isn't very pretty and is very inefficient but the error keeps saying that v is not defined

Comment: I get no error with your code in Python 3.5.3.

Comment: Why do you think this doesn't work? When I run your code, enter values, and press submit, the `save` function is called and `values` is properly set.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider declaring a variable, or a an instance of a context object (that you will define) at global scope to store your user inputs.

Then you will be able to read the user inputs later in another function.

Do not forget to use the keyword 'global' before modifying the global object in a different scope (like in a function). Have a look here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/

By example you could declare your global object/variable/whatever you need, along with your root Tkinter object.